# Possibility of different keys giving same ciphertext for a plaintext

Tags: encryption, cryptography, encryption-symmetric, des

Is it possible to have 2 different keys k1,k2 (not weak keys) for des algorithm such that

DES(P,k1)=DES(P,k2)=C             for a single Plaintext-CipherText Pair (P,C) ?

Comment: By making the assumption that DES behaves like a random function from 56 bits to 64 bits when the plaintext is fixed and the key varies, you can see that the probability that some k2 exists such that DES(P, k1) = DES(P, k2) is roughly 1/256 for a given P and k1. Thus, and again roughly, you'd expect to try only 256 different plaintexts before you find one that has the property you seek.

Comment: These should not be too hard to find, if I have my math correct. By the birthday problem the probability is 1/2 that after 2\*\*32 values of DES(P_i, K_i) are generated you will have a collision.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Yeah, but you need some nifty operations to keep the lookup & memory requirements down. Or at least a lot of memory, now that I do some calculations :)